# How do I write custom code that runs on server start?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I need to declare an instance of a custom class and add it to the Application collection as soon as our ASP.NET site starts on the server.

So far, we have it doing it on the first page load of a master page, but that can take a few seconds because this class is a little intensive, so the first user is required to wait a couple seconds while the web server completes its task.

So where do I need to go to do this?

Comment: stop adding your link to the question, or pay to advertise properly.

Comment: Just getting my Cleanup badge. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Global.asax page events, it is has what you need.

This should be helpfull

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: Yup. You probably want this method: protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Try this article: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721

Comment: Note that code in Application_Start won't run until someone makes a request to your application since it was restarted. ASP.NET 4 has an auto-start feature which would allow you to avoid this. More info here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Global.asax is the place to do it

Answer (score 0):

Application_Start in Global.asax